# Ubuntu Server stuck at 15.04 and cannot upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have tried to upgrade to 16.04 using `do-release-upgrade` but ended up with error `An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool.`

Google search result suggests to use `do-release-upgrade -d` but I am getting `No new release found`.

I have checked update-manager config is set to `Prompt=normal`

Any ideas how to get pass this barrier?

Answer (score 4):

Direct upgrading from 15.04 to 16.04 is not a supported path.  For Ubuntu the supported upgrades are from one release to the next release only.  Also supported is upgrading between LTS releases.  Skipping steps, is likely to result in a broken system.

Unfortunately this is going to make life difficult since 15.10 is [EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and support has also been dropped from the official archives. I don't believe you can easily make that intermediate upgrade using the standard `release-upgrade` tools.

You might be able to manually use the [old-archive sources](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) for 15.10.  So using something like these

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then you might be able to manually do an `apt-get update ; apt-get dist-upgrade`.

After that, you should be able to upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: This method works.

Comment: This method  seemed to work but then linux stopped with an error message at start

Answer (score 3):

start by editing /etc/apt/sources.list replacing vivid with xenial and then doing apt update and apt dist-upgrade. After that try do-release-upgrade again. Note that if your Ubuntu mirror does not have the required files any more, you can find another mirror which still has the old version available.